# Asp.NET database multi-lang design [Include HTML]

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, database-design, multilingual

,

I read lots of answer here and learn something about this topic but I need more help.Some pages in my project are getting the html(page body) from database.For my controls I use resx files and it works great, but now I need save the html values with multi-lang in my database.

I have a admin panel for my project and I edit sometimes the html or text or pictures in my editor and save it back to DB.I cache the html values in my website and get better performance for my project.But the html text parts is yet in my default lang I will create multi-lang.

I thought of a few possible solutions,

**First solution** was copying all of the same HTML data and create for all lang one by one

**First solution problem** : But later this doesnt make sense If I copy the values and create for other lang, then I had be repeating unnecessarily in my database the html values.

My **second solution** was like this :

this I hid it in the normal way in my DB (*only a part of html in one column*)

```
<li><a href="left-sidebar.html">Hello World</a></li>
<li><a href="right-sidebar.html">Hello Me</a></li>
```

Solution :

```
     <li><a href="left-sidebar.html">[HelloWorld]</a></li>
    <li><a href="right-sidebar.html">[HelloMe]</a></li>

    string newHtmlValue = oldValue.ReplaceByLang("[HelloWorld]", GetCulture();,"Hallo Welt");

   ***// GetCulture(); return for this example german !
```

I create a new table for the replace text like the key is [HelloWorld]

1(ROW)- [HelloWorld]  **eng**       Hello World

2(ROW)- [HelloWorld]  **german**    Hallo Welt

3(ROW)- [HelloWorld]  **fr**        bonjour tout le monde

and in my project I select the right html value by culture lang.

**Now my question is have you any better idea ?**

*I hope I've been clear and not messy, but if you need more informations I'll be glad to tell you more.Sorry for english.*

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to store all your localized string in single repository like - DB or Satellite assembly.

For Example if you choose DB as repository - Define 3 tables (minimal structure)

1.Locale - Define your locale

2.Resourcemaster - Define your source string and reference Key and this key should be unique in you application and define a standard format like Module_Control_Section ..

3.LocalizedResource -  Define your localized sting of Resourcemaster with Locale Key. Foreign key with ResourceMaster and Locale

In front End you can resole any string like control , Html string with localized string and Unique reference key.

Also Implement UI Caching / API caching for better performance.

Regards
Abdul

Comment: I wish I have only resx files as resource, but I can not edit resx file on runtime.If  I add something new in any of my html resources  with a new referencekey I need add this new referencekey to my resx file for multi-lang.I will try DB thank you for you answer Abdul :)